# How to plot other field in a single map with levelplot (LatticeExtra)?

Tags: r, maps, levelplot

I'm make meteorogical maps with levelplot function of LatticeExtra package. But, usully i need more than a field in a single map. For example: A single map with wind speed (shaded) and pressure (contour) (Fig1). But, i really dont know how make this maps compost in R. There any method for make this style maps in R?

Is possible at least make a single map with one field shaded and other contour?

[image: Fig1: Meteorological map with tree fiels: Pressure, wind speed and geopotential height]

Answer (score 0):

For example you can plot continuous data and contours like this (taken from the [levelplot examples](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lattice/versions/0.10-10/topics/levelplot)):

```
require(lattice)
require(stats)
attach(environmental)
ozo.m <- loess((ozone^(1/3)) ~ wind * temperature * radiation,
               parametric = c("radiation", "wind"), span = 1, degree = 2)
w.marginal <- seq(min(wind), max(wind), length = 50)
t.marginal <- seq(min(temperature), max(temperature), length = 50)
r.marginal <- seq(min(radiation), max(radiation), length = 4)
wtr.marginal <- list(wind = w.marginal, temperature = t.marginal,
                     radiation = r.marginal)
grid <- expand.grid(wtr.marginal)
grid[, "fit"] <- c(predict(ozo.m, grid))
contourplot(fit ~ wind * temperature | radiation, data = grid,
            cuts = 10, region = TRUE,
            xlab = "Wind Speed (mph)",
            ylab = "Temperature (F)",
            main = "Cube Root Ozone (cube root ppb)")
```

Also check out the examples on https://oscarperpinan.github.io/rastervis/#levelplot.

Comment: I do. But i need plot a lot of fields in same plot. In meteoroly is very common and powerful we use several fields in a single map.

Comment: Can you provide a data set that illustrates your problem?